# best way to test javascript bookmarklets in older versions of internet explorer (IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bookmarklet

I am developing a javascript bookmarklet that needs to be functional in IE 7 and IE 8. However I have IE 9 installed on my systems. Besides running separate instances of Windows that have older versions of IE installed, what are my options for being able to test a bookmarklet in IE 7 and IE 8? I have tried IETester, but haven't found a way to "install" a bookmarklet since there is no favorites bar to drag to.

Comment: one thing I noticed is that IE 7 and IE 8 don't actually allow you to "drag" a hyperlink to the favorites bar. you have to right-click a hyperlink, select Add to favorites, and then select the "favorites bar" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use virtual machines, which can be kind of a lot work to install. I personally use the tool [Cross Browser Testing](http://www.crossbrowsertesting.com). It's the best way to make sure it will work in every single browser.

It has two types of testing, screenshots and remote control. In your case you might want to remote control a virtual machine and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using virtual machines to run instances of windows with different combinations of the OS and the browser is the best that I've found when it comes to "manual" testing of things across browsers.

Some may say that running IE8 in 3 different VMs (XP, Vista, and 7) is overkill but I've found differences by doing this and when you don't have the flexibility to say "just upgrade", you don't have much choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [BrowseEmAll](http://www.browseemall.com) which can run IE 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11 on your local machine.